# How to check what is using a logical volume?

Tags: lvm, quota

Maybe there is a better way to do what I am trying to achieve, so let me describe the whole problem. My `/` and `/home` directories are on a separate LV. It happened so the `/` LV get out of space. I then backup my `/home` and try to remove it to be able to resize `/`. However, when I did login to root tty and try to umount the `/home` with `lvchange -a n /dev/trixxxy-vg/home` I get prompt that this logical volume is in use.

```
Logical volume trixxxy-vg/home contains a filesystem in use.
```

My `.emacs.d` and `.bashrc` directories in `/root` were links to `/home/user/` relevant, so I thought that can cause the problem, but after removing them nothing have changed.

I guess there is a way, that I am not aware of, to check what file is currently using the particular logical volume. Or may one force remove such partition?

Comment: Have your tried rebooting into single-user mode? That should allow you to umount /home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can typically use tools like `fuser` or `lsof` to see what files are currently in use. Here's an example where I'm going to use `lsof`.

#### Background

Here I have the following setup:

```
$ mount | grep lvm
/dev/mapper/lvm--raid-lvm0 on /export/raid0 type ext3 (rw)
```

So if we run `lsof` and grep for that mount `/export/raid0`:

```
$ lsof | grep '/export/raid0'
$
```

We get nothing. However if we `cd /export/raid0`:

```
$ lsof | grep '/export'
bash      32083      root  cwd       DIR              253,2          4096          2 /export/raid0
```

We see our Bash shell now accessing the LVM. Now lets `vi afile` while still in the directory `/export/raid0`:

```
$ lsof | grep '/export'
bash      32083      root  cwd       DIR              253,2          4096          2 /export/raid0
vi        32140      root  cwd       DIR              253,2          4096          2 /export/raid0
vi        32140      root    3u      REG              253,2          4096     278612 /export/raid0/.afile.swp
```

And `lsof` sees these accesses as well.

Comment: I find the multitude of lsof options confusing - is there a way to target this at the specific mount point, like `lsof +D /home` perhaps?

Comment: @steeldriver - yeah that switch can be used to do this as well, the thing I don't like about that is the `stat` of all the files as it walks down the tree.

Comment: @steeldriver - the warning in the man page: ....Further  note:  lsof  may process this option slowly and require a large amount of dynamic memory to do it.  This is because it must descend the entire directory tree, rooted at D,
                calling stat(2) for each file and directory, building a list of all the files it finds, and searching that list for a match with every open file.  When directory D is large,  these
                steps can take a long time, so use this option prudently....

Comment: @steeldriver - that's why I like doing it the way I showed with a simple `grep` 8-)